# Create in MS Word for Sharepoint Wiki

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, sharepoint-2013, rich-text-editor, rte

Actually I was searching for a RTE which has the below features :

1. change tracking.
2. Easy Copy from MS Word

Copy from word feature is available in most of the RTE's in the market but none of them are perfect, I like to have the feature as in sharepoint blog where you can create a blog post in word then add it in sharepoint.

Is there a alternative or set of tools/steps I can use to achieve this,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get in touch with [Native Documents](http://nativedocuments.wordsdk.com/).  They've been working on a web-based RTE with exactly the features you describe.

**Disclosure: I have an interest in this.**